# Python if statement returning

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having trouble with what is presumably a simple if statement. I am trying to pass through the type of VM file format to use. Even if I put VMDK or VHD, it still comes back with VMDK is an invalid type or VHD is an invalid type.

```
import sys
vmtype = sys.argv[3]
vmtype = str(vmtype).strip().upper()
## File format check
if vmtype is not ("VHD") or ("VMDK"):
    print vmtype + " is an invalid type"
    sys.exit()
```

I have tried the if statement with `!=` and not putting the parameters in parentheses. I have searched the web for a while and have tried what I have found and am still running into the same issue.

FYI I am running Python 2.6.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
if vmtype not in ("VHD", "VMDK"):
```

Your current code parses as:

```
if (vmtype is not ("VHD")) or ("VMDK"):
```

Which is obviously wrong. Since `("VMDK")` is a truthy value, the whole statement always be true. Therefore the `if` statement will always execute.

---

Note that even if you tried

```
if vmtype is not "VHD":
```

It would not work, because `is` tests identity, not value. You would use:

```
if vmtype != "VHD":
```

Comment: Other bug: `is` tests object identity instead of value equality. The `not in` solution happens to solve that problem too, but I'm not sure whether you noticed.

Comment: Doorknob, the not in works great. Thank you for the insight. I am still learning Python so I am prone to rookie mistakes.